# System.Security.SecureString error when executing Install-ADDSForest

Tags: powershell

I struggling a bit with Install-ADDSForest. I try to automate my AD creation for my home lab and the process terminated with the message "Install-ADDSForest : Cannot bind parameter 'SafeModeAdministratorPassword'. Cannot convert the "Pa$$w0rd" value of type "System.String" to type
"System.Security.SecureString"."
How I can feed the command with the correct syntax?

Thank you

```
$XML = [xml]@'
<Test>
    <Lab Active = "True" >
        <Task Name = "DomainController" Active = "True" Order = "1" ControllerName = "SRVDC01" DomainName = "&quot;LAB.lcl&quot;" CreateDnsDelegation = "$False" DatabasePath = "&quot;C:\Windows\NTDS&quot;" DomainMode = "&quot;WinThreshold&quot;" DomainNetbiosName = "&quot;LAB&quot;" ForestMode = "&quot;WinThreshold&quot;" InstallDns = "$True" LogPath= "&quot;C:\Windows\NTDS&quot;" NoRebootOnCompletion= "$True" SafeModeAdministratorPassword= "UGEkJHcwcmQ=" SysvolPath= "&quot;C:\Windows\SYSVOL&quot;" Force = "$True" />
    </Lab>
</Test>
'@
Function Decode-Password() {

    PARAM(

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$EncPassword = ""
        
    )
    
    BEGIN {}
    
    PROCESS {

        $Temp = [system.convert]::FromBase64String($EncPassword)
        $DecPassword = [system.text.encoding]::UTF8.Getstring($temp)
        
    }
    
    END { Return $DecPassword } 
    
}

If($($XML.Test.Lab.Active) -eq "True") {
    ForEach($ActiveTask in $XML.Test.Lab.Task | Sort-Object Order | Where-Object { $_.Active -eq "True" }){
        Switch($ActiveTask.Name){
            DomainController {
                If((Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "AD-Domain-Services"}).Installstate -eq "Available"){
                    Install-WindowsFeature -Name AD-Domain-Services -IncludeManagementTools -IncludeAllSubFeature
                }
                
                <#
                    - Default
                    - Windows Server 2003: “Win2003” or “2”
                    - Windows Server 2008: “Win2008” or “3”
                    - Windows Server 2008 R2: Win2008R2 or “4”
                    - Windows Server 2012: “Win2012” or “5”
                    - Windows Server 2012 R2: “Win2012R2” or “6”
                    - Windows Server 2016: “WinThreshold” or “7”
                #>

                $DCParams = [string]::Empty
                $Password = Decode-Password -EncPassword $($ActiveTask.SafeModeAdministratorPassword)
                
                If ($ActiveTask.DomainName -ne ""){
                    $DCParams += "-DomainName " + $ActiveTask.DomainName + ' `' + "`r`n"
                }
                If ($ActiveTask.CreateDnsDelegation -ne ""){
                    $DCParams += "-CreateDnsDelegation " + $ActiveTask.CreateDnsDelegation + ' `' + "`r`n"
                }
                If ($ActiveTask.DatabasePath -ne ""){
                    $DCParams += "-DatabasePath " + $ActiveTask.DatabasePath + ' `' + "`r`n"
                }
                If ($ActiveTask.DomainMode -ne ""){
                    $DCParams += "-DomainMode " + $ActiveTask.DomainMode + ' `' + "`r`n"
                }
                If ($ActiveTask.DomainNetbiosName -ne ""){
                    $DCParams += "-DomainNetbiosName " + $ActiveTask.DomainNetbiosName + ' `' + "`r`n"
                }
                If ($ActiveTask.ForestMode -ne ""){
                    $DCParams += "-ForestMode " + $ActiveTask.ForestMode + ' `' + "`r`n"
                }
                If ($ActiveTask.InstallDns -ne ""){
                    $DCParams += "-InstallDns " + $ActiveTask.InstallDns + ' `' + "`r`n"
                }
                If ($ActiveTask.LogPath -ne ""){
                    $DCParams += "-LogPath " + $ActiveTask.LogPath + ' `' + "`r`n"
                }
                If ($ActiveTask.NoRebootOnCompletion -ne ""){
                    $DCParams += "-NoRebootOnCompletion " + $ActiveTask.NoRebootOnCompletion + ' `' + "`r`n"
                }
                If ($ActiveTask.SafeModeAdministratorPassword -ne ""){
                    $DCParams += "-SafeModeAdministratorPassword " + '"$Password"' + ' `' + "`r`n"
                }
                If ($ActiveTask.SysvolPath -ne ""){
                    $DCParams += "-SysvolPath " + $ActiveTask.SysvolPath + ' `' + "`r`n"
                }

                If ($ActiveTask.Force -ne ""){
                    $DCParams += "-Force " + $ActiveTask.Force + ' `' + "`r`n"
                }

                #$x = $DCParams.TrimEnd(' `' + "`r`n")
                #$x
                

                $TrimDCParams = $DCParams.TrimEnd(' `' + "`r`n")
                $DCPromo = Invoke-Expression "Install-ADDSForest ` $TrimDCParams"
                $DCPromo

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, you can't use a regular old `[string]` in place of a `[SecureString]`. Use `ConvertTo-SecureString` to create one from an existing string:

```
$Password = Decode-Password -EncPassword $($ActiveTask.SafeModeAdministratorPassword)
$EncryptedPassword = $Password |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```

---

In order to bind such a value to a parameter, you'll need to stop constructing the command expression as a string, and instead take advantage of **splatting**:

```
# Create hashtable to hold the parameter arguments
$DCParams = @{}

# Go through all the possible parameter names 
$paramNames = -split @'
DomainName
CreateDnsDelegation
DatabasePath
DomainMode
DomainNetbiosName
ForestMode
InstallDns
LogPath
NoRebootOnCompletion
SysvolPath
Force
'@

foreach($paramName in $paramNames)
{
    # Add arguments to parameter table if present
    if($ActiveTask.$paramName -ne ""){
        $DCParams[$paramName] = $ActiveTask.$paramName
    }
}

# Add the safe mode password
if($ActiveTask.SafeModeAdministratorPassword -ne ''){
    $Password = Decode-Password -EncPassword $($ActiveTask.SafeModeAdministratorPassword)
    $EncryptedPassword = $Password |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

    $DCParams['SafeModeAdministratorPassword'] = $EncryptedPassword
}

# Pass table of named parameter arguments to command using the `@` splat operator
$DCPromo = Install-ADDSForest @DCParams
```

See the [`about_Splatting` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1#splatting-with-hash-tables) for more information about argument splatting in PowerShell

Comment: Thats genious! I definately understand the way that you pointing on and I've give you code a try. It ends with an error like this:
Test-ADDSForestInstallation : Cannot bind parameter 'DomainMode'. Cannot convert value ""WinThreshold"" to type 
"Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Deployment.Types.DomainMode". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name "WinThreshold" to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the 
following enumerator names and try again:
Win2008, Win2008R2, Win2012, Win2012R2, WinThreshold, Default".

Any idea?

Comment: @CptRetro Looks like you might have to trim the quotation marks: `$DCParams[$paramName] = $($ActiveTask.$paramName).Trim('"')`

Comment: Thank you again @Mathias R. Jessen. There is another error like "Cannot convert 'System.String' to the type 'System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter'" but i try to get dir of it